# Is it necessary to create a constraint on a "secondary label" on Neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am parsing some CSV files to import that data on my Neo4j Enterprise single-instance database, and I set the NODE KEY type constraints on every node label so it is sped up as suggested by the docs, but I found nothing mentioning constraints on "secondary labels", that is, a label `MainObj`/`SecondaryObj` I am setting to a node after doing a merge on the primary key `code` with the "primary label" `Obj`.

I have noticed some slowness with this label on big CSVs (first-stage development with smaller CSVs didn't hint any type of performance issues) but I am unsure if I should blame this, and wonder if with a constraint on those 2 labels it would be resolved, and if so, what keys should I use on those constraints since I am not using them to do queries on import-time (only later when they're available on read queries from GraphQL)

This is the constraint I got:

```
label: Obj
key: "code"
keys: ["code"]
unique: true
```

This is the Cypher with the Merges:

```
// main obj
MERGE (mainObj:Obj {code: row.objs.main.code})
SET mainObj.make = row.objs.main.make,
    mainObj.isMain = true,
    mainObj:MainObj

// secondary obj
MERGE (secondaryObj:Obj {code: row.objs.secondary.code})
SET secondaryObj.make = row.objs.secondary.make,
    secondaryObj.isSecondary = true,
    secondaryObj:SecondaryObj
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "secondary label"? Your query is only showing a single node label (`Obj`). "mainObj" and "secondaryObj" are only used by the query as variables, not "labels".

Comment: @cybersam At the end of the `SET` statement I am assigning a label to the merged node with mainObj:MainObj, which is the syntax to set a label on a matched/merged node. [docs](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/set/#set-set-a-label-on-a-node)

Comment: You should consider batching larger data imports

Comment: Your query is taking advantage of the `:Obj(code)` [index](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/administration/indexes-for-search-performance/) (that is created automatically by your existing constraint). Your query will not use any other indexes, so adding additional constraints on your "secondary" labels will not help speed up importing (and will actually slow it down, since there are now 2 indexes to update). Also, you should consider whether you should use [ON CREATE](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/merge/#merge-merge-with-on-create) before your `SET` clauses.

Comment: @cybersam I do use `ON CREATE`, that code snippet is actually a little bigger than that, I just pasted what I considered was necessary (the `MERGE` with the first label, and the `SET` with the second one) and cleaned it of all the "unnecessary statements" to make the question concise.

Comment: These two statements make sure to add that "second" label if the same object is found to be on that other column. This way a node could have 3 labels, `Obj`, `MainObj` and `SecondaryObj`, if it meets the requirement to be on both columns.